# gdb script: How can a script determine if it is invoked under `gdb` or `gdb-multiarch`?

Tags: gdb

I'd like to define a command which does X under `gdb-multiarch`, but prints out a helpful message when run under normal `gdb`.  How can my script determine which of the two its run under?

Why? When I start gdb-multiarch, I can bind to a qemu-arm session.  When I try that in gdb, I get bizarre errors.  It's easy to forget and run gdb (and not -multiarch), and I want to my `bind-to-qemu` tell me "This must be run under gdb-multiarch".

Comment: http://xyproblem.info may be relevant here.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Clarified accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question *presumes* that there is *some* difference between `gdb` and `gdb-multiarch`, but there doesn't have be any such difference.

Presumably on the OS you are using the `gdb` and `gdb-multiarch` are configured differently, with `gdb` only supporting native architecture, while `gdb-multiarch` supports cross-architecture debugging.

Presumably what you *actually* want to detect is that the target-architecture you need (`arm` ?) is / isn't supported by the current binary.

In the `bind-to-qemu` user-defined function, you can try to `set architecture arm`.

If that errors out, the rest of `bind-to-qemu` should not execute.